IEEE 802.11s Mesh: IP Address to MAC Correlation?
I'm attempting to better understand IEEE 802.11s wireless mesh networks and I don't understand how IP addresses are correlated to MAC addresses if the mesh channel has a different MAC address than the Wifi or wired LAN channel.
To give an example, suppose I have a small MBSS of 10 stations, 192.1.0.1 through 192.1.0.10.  I am logged into 192.1.0.1 and ping 192.1.0.7.  My current understanding is that the ARP will return the layer 3 MAC address used by the WiFi channel, not the Layer 2 MAC address needed by the HWMP.  In other words, how is IP to Mesh MAC address look-up achieved if the MAC addresses of the Wifi (or wired LAN) are not the same as the mesh channel MAC address for the destination channel?

The layer-2 address of the next hop is dynamic so the HWMP broadcasts RREQs to find it, and that will return the layer-2 address to which you are referring.

Thank you for your answer. I understand that a mesh station that needs to find a route will initiate a route request.  My question is how does the originating mesh station ascertain the MAC address for the destination route if the MAC address of the destination station's IP address is different than what is being used by the IEEE 802.11s mesh?  Should the MAC addresses be the same for layer-2 and layer-3 or can they be different?  Maybe another way to ask the question is how are the layer-3 MAC addresses of the various stations in a MBSS correlated with the layer-2 addresses?

The MAC address of an interface is the MAC address of that interface. Remember that the 802.11 frame header is much more complex than that of ethernet. Wi-Fi has places for four MAC addresses (source, destination, transmitter, and receiver) vs. that of ethernet that only has source and destination MAC addresses.

I probably need to get down to specifics of what's causing me this mental block in understanding.  I am trying to cobble together 2nd hand routers into a mesh for a non-profit. I'm using OpenWrt.  OpenWrt by default creates a bridge interface for the Ethernet and Wi-Fi interfaces, named br-lan, for the local area network (LAN).  This virtual Ethernet switch is assigned a MAC address.
When creating a mesh channel, while it is assigned to the LAN, it is given a different MAC address than the virtual switch, br-lan.   I now have two MAC addresses and I don't understand how they are correlated.

Unfortunately, your OpenWRT is off-topic here, so we cannot help with that.

Is OpenWrt off-topic because it is Open Source or because it is targeted at Consumer grade products?

Anyway, thanks for your answers and apologies.  I'll go back to the IEEE spec and review the frame headers.

Consumer-grade. To be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. See this Meta answer about that.
